# Receiver of LocalBroadcast not working for System broadcast

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, localbroadcastmanager

I have a service from where i can broadcast using LocalBroadcastManager.

```
Intent downloadIntent = new Intent();
downloadIntent.setAction(BroadcastActions.DOWNLOAD_APPOINTMENTS.toString());
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(downloadIntent);
```

In a Test activity i m receiving this broadcasts like following.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(String.valueOf(BroadcastActions.DOWNLOAD_APPOINTMENTS));
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

In the same Test activity i added another action called ACTION_FOUND to get bluetooth enabled device.
Since i m using LocalBroadCast Manager i couldn't receive broadcast of system if it found any bluetooth devices. Can anybody help on this to receive both system and local broadcasts..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anybody help on this to receive both system and local broadcasts..?

A `LocalBroadcastReceiver` is only useful within your own app hence the use of the term "local".

There's nothing stopping you from using more than one `BroadcastReceiver` though. Simply create another one to receive the system broadcasts.